# 似たような変数にまとめて値を代入する方法

Tags: python

以下のようなコードで、a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3 の6行をより短く変数を定義したいのですが、何かいい方法はありますか？ `.format()` が使えるかと思ったのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
a3 = 3
b1 = a1**2
b2 = a2**2
b3 = a3**2
```

Answer (score 2):

`a*`の変数にはそれぞれの値を, `b*`の変数には共通の計算式を
与えるなら, こんな風

```py
>>> a1,a2,a3 = 1,2,3
>>> b1,b2,b3 = [n**2 for n in(a1,a2,a3)]
```

---

##### 追記

(項目が多い場合など)ひとまとめのセット用いるなら, こんな風にも

```py
vals = a1,a2,a3 = 1,2,3
b1,b2,b3 = [n**2 for n in vals]
```

Answer (score 1):

リストにすると良いかと思います。

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [i**2 for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 以降であればセイウチ演算子(walrus operator)を使って以下の様に。

```py
b1, b2, b3 = (a1:=1)**2, (a2:=2)**2, (a3:=3)**2
```

※ お勧めはしません